# strncpy segfaults at ssse3 altough all parameters look correct

Tags: c++, strncpy

I have the following function call in my code:

```
 strncpy(path_ptr,index_str,path_len);
```

Printing the arguments via gdb I get:

```
gdb print path_ptr
# print path_ptr
# $277 = 0x7fffeb336636 \"7:0]\"

gdb print index_str
# print index_str
# $280 = \"0]\", '\\0' <repeats 14 times>, \"\\360\\256\\256\\003\"

gdb print path_len
# print path_len
# $283 = 0x4
```

Which, means, if I understand it correctly that the 4 characters: \"0]\", '\0' '\0', will be copied from index_str to path_ptr. This seems ok, but stepping over this line gives the following segfault:

```
# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
# 0x0000003cd9f34cc3 in __strncpy_ssse3 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Any clue why? full code snippet is below for reference:

```
static int uvm_hdl_set_vlog_partsel(char *path, p_vpi_vecval value, PLI_INT32 flag)
{
  char *path_ptr = path;
  int path_len, idx;
  svLogicVecVal bit_value;

  path_len = strlen(path);
  path_ptr = (char*)(path+path_len-1);

  if (*path_ptr != ']')
    return 0;

  while(path_ptr != path && *path_ptr != ':' && *path_ptr != '[')
    path_ptr--;

  if (path_ptr == path || *path_ptr != ':')
    return 0;

  while(path_ptr != path && *path_ptr != '[')
    path_ptr--;

  if (path_ptr == path || *path_ptr != '[')
    return 0;

  int lhs, rhs, width, incr;

  // extract range from path
  if (sscanf(path_ptr,"[%u:%u]",&lhs, &rhs)) {
    char index_str[20];
    int i;
    path_ptr++;
    path_len = (path_len - (path_ptr - path));
    incr = (lhs>rhs) ? 1 : -1;
    width = (lhs>rhs) ? lhs-rhs+1 : rhs-lhs+1;
    vpi_printf((PLI_BYTE8*)"LHS %u RHS %u", lhs, rhs);

    // perform set for each individual bit
    for (i=0; i < width; i++) {
      sprintf(index_str,"%u]",rhs);
      strncpy(path_ptr,index_str,path_len);
      svGetPartselLogic(&bit_value,value,i,1);
      rhs += incr;
      if (!uvm_hdl_set_vlog(path,&bit_value,flag))
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `path_ptr` points at a constant string?

Comment: That code looks like it would write past the end of the space the caller allocated for `path` but I obviously can't say for sure without seeing how the caller allocates path and seeing the other data.  But even writing past the end of `path` is an unlikely cause of seg fault at that spot.  If `path` pointed to a local buffer inside a function that had exited before the function you showed even started, that would fit the debug info you posted.

Comment: @MatsPetersson you got me on something. Arguments were not defined as const char, but the original function call is func("x.y.z[7:0]"). When I fixed that, the crash is gone, so thanks a lot. If you want to put this as answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying character constants is undefined, and in many modern compilers, character literals are stored in either read-only data-space or code-space. These are both "read only", meaning the storage can not be written to.

Since C++ accepts, for backwards compatibilyt, to assign a non-const `char*` with a character constant, you can come up with something like this:

```
 char *p = "Foo";
 char *q = "Bar";
 ... more code goes here so it's hard to see what p and q are.
 strcpy(p, q);
```

which would crash.

A partial solution is to consistently write:

```
const char *p = "Foo";
const char *q = "Bar";
```

Then the compiler will point out that `p` is `const` whenever you try to pass it to something that doesn't expect `const`. But it may not play well with old-style code that uses `char *` when it actually should be `const char *`, of course.

If you actually want to be able to modify such a string:

```
char p[10] = "Foo";
```

beware of writing outside of `p`'s size tho'.

Better yet, use C++ `std::string`, then you don't have any of these problems.